# WorkingPrecision and NDSolve Method Plugin Framework

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm studying some new numerical integration algorithms using `NDSolve` Method Framework to specify them. When I try to set `WorkingPrecision` option to other value than `MachinePrecision` I get the following error message:

> NDSolve::bdstep: The Step function for Method -> CRK4 returned {0.03529465924388010,0.07025569022824054}, which is not an acceptable form. >>

Here I apply the first `CRK4` definition from the [official tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html) for the Van der Pol equation:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
system = 
 NDSolveProblem[
   {{Y1'[T] == Y2'[T], Y2'[T] == -Y1[T] + 2 (1 - Y1[T]^2) Y2[T]}, 
    {Y1[0] == 0, Y2[0] == 2}, {Y1[T], Y2[T]}, {T, 0, 30}, {}, {}, {}}];
vars = system["DependentVariables"]; 
time = system["TimeData"];
sol1 = 
  Flatten[vars /. NDSolve[system, Method -> CRK4, WorkingPrecision -> 16]]
```

I have little experience working with Wolfram *Mathematica* and I will be very grateful to get a clue how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the definitions so that the step output is a list:

```
CRK4[]["Step"[rhs_, h_, t_, x_, xp_]] := Module[{k0, k1, k2, k3},
  k0 = h xp;
  k1 = h rhs[t + h/2, x + k0/2];
  k2 = h rhs[t + h/2, x + k1/2];
  k3 = h rhs[t + h, x + k2];
  {(k0 + 2  k1 + 2  k2 + k3)/6}]        (* <-- List *)

CRK4[___]["StepInput"] = {"F"["T", "X"], "H", "T", "X", "XP"};
CRK4[___]["StepOutput"] = {"XI"};       (* <-- List *)
```

Then both the `MachinePrecision` and `WorkingPrecision -> 16` code return comparable solutions:

```
sol1mp = Flatten[vars /. NDSolve[system, Method -> CRK4, StartingStepSize -> 0.01]];
sol1 = Flatten[vars /. NDSolve[system, Method -> CRK4, StartingStepSize -> 0.01, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 16]];

Plot[sol1mp - sol1 // Evaluate, Evaluate@system["TimeData"], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, why does it work? Well, the check takes place in internal code that cannot be traced.  So I don't know.  I don't know if it's a bug or an error in the example.  There is quite a bit of documentation on `NDSolve[]`, but there seems to be a lot that is not explained, too.  There may be a reason for wanting the two return types.

I can share this tip.  If you use the form

```
CRK4[___]["StepOutput"] = "XI";
```

it seems the output of the `"Step"` method needs to be a ***packed array*** or you'll get the error.  That means machine precision only.  If the output form is `{"XI"}`, then `NDSolve` seems to tolerate any numeric array of the appropriate dimensions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solves the problem.

Comment: @Sheldon You're welcome.